# Using isMock() function (to find mockLocation) giving error

Tags: android, mock-location

I am trying to find if the location is from mock provider as shown below

```
  Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 30)
     allLocationData.put("isMock", location.isFromMockProvider());
  else if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31)
     allLocationData.put("isMock", location.isMock());
```

Handling mock location is different in `Api <= 30` and `Api >= 31`. Hence, `isMock()` to be used for `Api >= 30`. But When I ran above code getting following error

```
  error: cannot find symbol allLocationData.put("isMock", location.isMock());
                                                              ^
  symbol:   method isMock()
  location: variable location of type Location
```

Am I missing any import statements here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the isFromMockProvider() or the isMock() methods on the Location class will always throw an error here since only one of those methods can be present based on the API version of the Android device.

So we need to dynamically invoke the corresponding method in this scenario. And Reflection API is a way to go.

Your code can be changed as below using Reflection to dynamically invoke the method.

```
String methodName = "";
Boolean isMock = false;
Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
**//Determine the method name to be invoked**
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 30) {
    methodName = "isFromMockProvider";
} else if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
        methodName = "isMock";
}
     
**//Invoke the method dynamically using Reflection**
Class<? extends Location> cls = location.getClass();
try {
    Method decMethod = cls.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
    isMock = (Boolean) decMethod.invoke(location);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Handle exception
}
            
**//Store the result finally**
allLocationData.put("isMock", isMock);
```

Comment: getting two errors `cannot find symbol Method` and `Cannot resolve method 'invoke(android.location.Location)'`

Comment: Please add the import statement import java.lang.reflect.*;